# Percona cacti template is not possible to recognize installed cacti on my system

Tags: templates, percona, cacti

I have deployed latest cacti from source on my system. It is running OK but when I install percona-cacti-templates. I see an error dependency:

```
warning: percona-cacti-templates-1.1.4-1.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID cd2efd2a: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        cacti >= 0.8.6 is needed by percona-cacti-templates-1.1.4-1.noarch
```

I download binary rpm percona cacti template from here:

```
https://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-monitoring-plugins/
```

How do I make percona cacti template to understand I have installed cacti on my system ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Read the cacti documentation on how to import templates.

1. Go to the Percona website and download only the templates.
2. In Cacti Click Import and import the templates.
3. It should work.

Comment: I forget I don't update answer for my question. I solved it. Just import cacti template from tar.gz Don't use rpm.